# Programmatically delete CCK field value

Tags: 6, entities

I have content type with Photos ImageField. I need to create some moderation view to show all photos and "delete" link to delete appropriate photo. How can I programmatically delete value from CCK field (in general not only ImageField but any field type)?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to check the ImageField array to see what needs to be changed but for D6 but it   should be something like the below:

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$node->field_photo[0]['value'] = NULL;
node_save($node);
```

Just change the field name to what you are using and change the $nid to the node id #.

Comment: This appears to be the best approach in Drupal 7 too. There are heaps of field functions, but none of them seem able to single out and delete one specific field entry.

Answer (score 0):

WestieUK has a correct general expression. However, the vague question presents two potential cases for Filefield/Imagefield here:

1. Delete all references to that file from all nodes -> `filefield_file_delete($file);`.
2. Delete only that node's reference to the file -> Use WestieUK's method.

If there never are multiple node associations for the files in your structure (usual behavior in Filefield/Imagefield), method #1 is safe and simple to use for case #2 as well.
If the file is no longer referenced, do not forget to also remove the entry from the file tables and delete the file from disk with `file_delete($path);`.